# Is there any way to lock all form except one throught Qt?

Tags: c++, forms, qt, user-interface, global

My idea is to make a sort of log in form.
This gui must be the only active in the system.
so the question , how to do this with Qt framework (c++)?

Comment: What do you mean by `only active in the system`?

Comment: You mean you only want your application window to be accessible and not allow the user to interact with any other window on the desktop?

Comment: Yes user99545 is what i would enjoy to do  .

Comment: On a general-purpose desktop PC, this is an unrealistic requirement and, if possible, would have dire security implications. You building a kiosk app?

Comment: no only for general-purpose desktop PC . What i should do is only  a log-in form  that unlock the pc .

Answer (score 0):

You can call showFullScreen() and raise() on your Qt window, and that would cause your app to take over the entire screen... but the user could still Alt-Tab to another app.  I don't think there's much you can do about that from within Qt; you'd probably have to drop down and use some kind of OS-level API to prevent that.